# PHP inverse for array_diff_assoc(), remove duplicate values

Tags: php, array-difference

I haver permissions levels system, so i need remove from my array my previos selected permissions. For example:

```
My permissions:  read, write
All permissions: read, write, update, delete
I need return:   update, delete
```

The problem: `array_diff_assoc`() compare exact keys, [0] = [0], i need compare values not keys, and return all permission without, my previos selected permissions, not removed values.

```
res['all_withou_pre_selected_permissions'] = array_diff_assoc($all_permissions,$res['my_permissions']);
print_r($res['all_withou_pre_selected_permissions']);
```

My arrays and return

```
My permissions
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["Modulo"]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    [0]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    ["Tipo"]=>
    string(9) "Adicionar"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Adicionar"
    ["Nome"]=>
    string(3) "kin"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "kin"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["Modulo"]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    [0]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    ["Tipo"]=>
    string(7) "Excluir"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Excluir"
    ["Nome"]=>
    string(3) "kin"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "kin"
  }
}

All Permissions
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Modulo"]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    [0]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    ["Tipo"]=>
    string(9) "Adicionar"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Adicionar"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Modulo"]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    [0]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    ["Tipo"]=>
    string(6) "Editar"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Editar"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Modulo"]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    [0]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    ["Tipo"]=>
    string(7) "Excluir"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Excluir"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Modulo"]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    [0]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    ["Tipo"]=>
    string(3) "Ler"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Ler"
  }

Return of PHP code

array(6) {
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Modulo"]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    [0]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    ["Tipo"]=>
    string(7) "Excluir"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Excluir"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Modulo"]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    [0]=>
    string(15) "Administradores"
    ["Tipo"]=>
    string(3) "Ler"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Ler"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't use [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff)?

```
$my = array( 'read', 'write');
$all = array( 'read', 'write', 'update', 'delete');

var_dump( array_diff( $all, $my));
```

**Output:**

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  string(6) "update"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "delete"
}
```

Comment: Wrong try this:
<?php
$my = array(
        array('Module'=>'Administrator', 'Permission'=>'write'),
        array('Module'=>'Administrator', 'Permission'=>'read')
      );

echo '<pre>';
print_r($my);
echo '</pre>';

$all = array(
        array('Module'=>'Administrator', 'Permission'=>'write'),
        array('Module'=>'Administrator', 'Permission'=>'update'),
        array('Module'=>'Administrator', 'Permission'=>'remove'),
        array('Module'=>'Administrator', 'Permission'=>'read')
      );

echo '<pre>';
print_r($all);
echo '</pre>';

var_dump( array_diff( $all, $my));
?>

Answer (score 1):

The *union* of two arrays:

```
$union = array_unique( array_merge( $arr1, $arr2 ) );
```

The [*intersection*](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-intersect.php) of them:

```
$intersect = array_intersect( $arr1, $arr2 );
```

The *difference* :

```
$diff = array_diff( $arr1, $arr2 );
```

The *symetric difference* <sup>[source](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_24.htm)</sup>:

```
$sym_diff = array_merge( array_diff( $arr1, $arr2 ), array_diff( $arr2, $arr1 ) );
```

Another possibility would be to write a simple [`FilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.filteriterator.php).

*As there was no other question in the Google SERPs, I'm leaving an answer on this old question.*